# CSS - individual background-image

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML code:

```
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

... and following CSS:

```
.avatar {
    background: url(img.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 5px;
}
```

But the image won't show.
How I can fix this?

(And yes, I already searched years for my answer, but nothing found.)

My entire code:

```
<body onload="countdown()">
<div class="avatar"></div>
<img src="..." class="logo" />
    <div id="box"><b><u><?php echo $titel; ?></u></b>
        <br /><br />
        <?php echo $text1; ?><br /><br />
        Lorem ipsum.. <span id="countdown" style="color: white"></span>Lorem ipsum..<br />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is img.png located in the same folder where .html is located?

Comment: Please give the *rendered* HTML, not the PHP side, when asking questions dealing with HTML

Answer (score 3):

Your div doesn't have a width or height, that's why it won't show the background image, try giving it a width & height,

```
.avatar {
    background: url(img.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 5px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

If this doesn't work, there's something wrong with your image link.

Answer (score 0):

Make these modifications :)

```css
.avatar{
  background-image: url("img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire code, you don't have width or height 
see http://jsfiddle.net/2ms2dpww/

```
.avatar {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
}
```

## EDIT

It is not working because you closed the div see this http://jsfiddle.net/2ms2dpww/1/

i closed this at the end everything worked fine

```
<div class="avatar">
```

Comment: It's not mir entire code, i have more content. When i add height and width, my content gets down.

Comment: @Aarivex show your code in a fiddle then it would be more better